# JSON Deserialization with property default value not working

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization

I am using Newtonsoft to deserialize data from a file. When I deserialize two different instances from two different sets of data, both instances' property ends up having the same value. I have created a small project to repro the issue. Here are my 2 JSON files

File1.json:

```
{
  "Name": "File1",
  "SomeProperty":
  {
    "Value": 1 
  }
}
```

File2.json:

```
{
  "Name": "File2",
  "SomeProperty":
  {
    "Value": 2 
  }
}
```

SomeProperty.cs

```
namespace Json
{
  public class SomePropertyDto
  {
    public static SomePropertyDto Default = new SomePropertyDto
    {
      Value = 0
    };

    public int Value { get; set; }
  }
}
```

FileDataDto.cs

```
namespace Json
{
  public class FileDataDto
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SomePropertyDto SomeProperty
    {
      get => someProperty;
      set => someProperty = value;
    }

    private SomePropertyDto someProperty = SomePropertyDto.Default;
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Json
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string json1 = File.ReadAllText("File1.json");
      string json2 = File.ReadAllText("File2.json");

      FileDataDto fileData1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileDataDto>(json1);
      FileDataDto fileData2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileDataDto>(json2);
    }
  }
}
```

After deserializing both instances of FileDataDto, both their SomeProperty values are the same. However if I do not initialise the FileDataDto someProperty field to SomePropertyDto.Default,

```
private SomePropertyDto someProperty;// = SomePropertyDto.Default;
```

it works correctly. If I include the initialisation to the default value

```
private SomePropertyDto someProperty = SomePropertyDto.Default;
```

after deserializing fileData1, the SomeProperty value equals 1 as expected. However, after deserializing fileData2, both fileData1 and FileData2 instances' SomeProperty value equals 2 which is not what is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializerSettings.cs#L46, the default object creation setting is "Auto", which means https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/ObjectCreationHandling.cs#L34

> Reuse existing objects, create new objects when needed.

So when your Default object is there, someProperty stay this, the same, shared object for all FileDataDto instances.

Provide customized JsonSerializerSettings (with ObjectCreationHandling set to Replace) if you need that Default value.

Comment: Thanks for this. So one has to be careful not to have default values for object properties in classes you want to deserialize as this can cause quite a few bugs, as it did in my case.